# How to use jQuery selector to find last row in table that textboxes have values?

Tags: jquery, selector

Let's say I have following HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="date-input" />
        <input type="text" class="date-input" />
        <input type="text" class="number-input" />
        <input type="text" class="number-input" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="date-input" />
        <input type="text" class="date-input" />
        <input type="text" class="number-input" />
        <input type="text" class="number-input" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="date-input" />
        <input type="text" class="date-input" />
        <input type="text" class="number-input" />
        <input type="text" class="number-input" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to find out the last row in the table that any of these textboxes have value. Instead of looping through them, is there a quick jQuery selector I can leverage?

Comment: Use `each()` & check for fields having values

Comment: None of them have a value attribute. Do you mean where the user has entered something? I don't think that can be done with a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no in-built selector to get a non-empty input. However you can use `filter()` to find the last input with a value, then get the `closest()` `tr` from that element:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.foo').removeClass('foo'); // only for this demo, you may not need this

  var $tr = $('input').filter(function() {
    return this.value.trim();
  }).last().closest('tr');

  $tr.addClass('foo');
});
```

```css
.foo { background-color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="date-input" />
      <input type="text" class="date-input" />
      <input type="text" class="number-input" />
      <input type="text" class="number-input" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="date-input" />
      <input type="text" class="date-input" />
      <input type="text" class="number-input" />
      <input type="text" class="number-input" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="date-input" />
      <input type="text" class="date-input" />
      <input type="text" class="number-input" />
      <input type="text" class="number-input" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button>Highlight row</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of the last input of the last row, you can use `$("table tr:last input:last")`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($("table tr:last input:last").val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="date-input" />
      <input type="text" class="date-input" />
      <input type="text" class="number-input" />
      <input type="text" class="number-input" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="date-input" />
      <input type="text" class="date-input" />
      <input type="text" class="number-input" />
      <input type="text" class="number-input" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="date-input" />
      <input type="text" class="date-input" />
      <input type="text" class="number-input" />
      <input type="text" class="number-input" value="last" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The question is about finding the row of the last *non-empty* input, not the last input itself.

Comment: I didn't read non-empty anywhere. Seems, I misunderstood the question.